# How to add access control to a MongoDB database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

In my project, I would like to connect to mongodb database.

I have a connection string to do this

**Web.config**

```
<add name="MongoDB" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/?safe=true" />
```

But I want to access to db with username and password so I created an admin user in mongodb for my db but I can still access to db without username and password.

**Web.config**

```
<add name="MongoDB" connectionString="mongodb://username:password@91.93.201.99:27017/?safe=true" />
```

I added username and password to connection string, connection is succesfull but when i use connection string without credentials, it is successfull too.

username and password are useless.

How can i add access control to my mongodb database.

Comment: Do you actually do something with the database after connecting to it? AFAIK credentials are only checked when you perform an operation, not on creating the connection object.

Comment: Yes I added some records to database without needing credentials

Comment: Can you show us how you set up MongoDB for authorization? Can you post example code showing not needing credentials? Ideally in the shell so it's not convoluted to verify what the connection is. It's just not the case that MongoDB will let you violate the authorization scheme, so you must be doing something incorrectly, or failing to do something.